# Python 3 - Nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have created 4 loop to loop into 4 different lists
put the last for is the only one that going in loop

```
ID =['2098','116','121']
major=['Electrical', 'Accounting', 'Commerce']
dgree=['Diploma', 'Diploma','Bachelor']
uni=['Institute', 'British careers training college', 'University Bharatidarsan']
for u in uni:
    for d in dgree:
        for m in major:
            for x in ID:
```

it should go the first for then the second for then the 3rd for then the 4th for and back again to the first and so on

Comment: What do you want to do in those loops ?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify for yourself what is happening, you can add `print(u,d,m,x)` inside the inner loop.

Then you will see, that first uni[0], dgree[0], major[0] followed by ID [0], then ID[1] and ID[2] is printed. We looped over all three IDs, so next there will be uni[0], dgree[0], major[1] followed again by ID[0] etc.

As explained in your comment, you want to loop over the four lists simultaneously. You can use one for loop and `zip` to do so:

```
for (u,d,m,x) in zip(uni,dgree,major,ID): 
    print(u,d,m,x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to clarify I want the output to be first uni[0], dgree[0], major[0],ID[0] then second time will be uni[1], dgree[1], major[1] , ID[1] ...      any idea how to make it ??

Comment: Ok now I understand what you are looking for, just edited my answer